# IPython has lag on ConEmu, and only on ConEmu

Tags: python, conemu, ipython

I'm running Python 3.7.3 through IPython 7.5.0 on ConEmu 19.6.23.0, using Windows 10 Pro. Whenever I run IPython on ConEmu, I experience lag. For example, on IPython's interpreter I input `1+1` and hit Enter, part of the prompt disappears, and after less than a second `Out [2]: 2` is printed, then another short time is elapsed until `Out [3]:` is printed. Nevertheless, if I write something during this lag, this input will appear in the final `Out [3]: <something>`, so I guess the problem is related to a drop of the refreshing rate of the console emulator while executing a python command on IPython.

Python works perfectly everywhere, included from ConEmu. ConEmu works flawlessly and without any lag at any circumstance but when I run IPython. Finally, IPython runs smoothly on cmd.exe and PowerShell, and only refreshes slowly on ConEmu. My main problem is that I don't even know how to track the origin of the problem, so working on a solution is basically impossible for me.

Then, what could be the cause of this lag and how could I solve it?

Thank you in advance.